# How to plot a bar graph from nested dictionary without using Pandas when keys are not uniform?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I have a nested dictionary like this:

```
{'uvvm': {'0-250ms': 96, '500-750ms': 2}, 'usvv': {'0-250ms': 1},
 'unsharedChunksVirtualVolume': {'0-250ms': 21}, 'ubvv': {'0-250ms': 60, '250-500ms': 2, '500-750ms': 3},
 'unbvvh': {'0-250ms': 1}, 'ssvv': {'0-250ms': 101, '250-500ms': 1},
 'sscc': {'0-250ms': 2}, 'sc': {'500-750ms': 2},
 'qvv': {'0-250ms': 200, '500-750ms': 5}, 'qas': {'0-250ms': 4}}
```

The inner keys `0-250`, `250-500`, `500-750` etc., are not uniform for all outer keys. I need to plot a bar graph **without using pandas** as we need to collect as part of support bundle and cant have `pandas` installed in customer machines. Please provide a way.

```
op = dict(list(dictLatency.items())[i:i+10])
print(op)
inner_keys = ['0-250ms', '250-500ms', '500-750ms', '750-1000ms', '1000-1250ms',
              '1250-1500ms', '1500-1750ms', '1750-2000ms', '2000-2250ms']
newDict = a:[[i, b.get(i, 0)] for i in inner_keys] for a, b in op.items()
print(newDict)

labels = op.keys()
```

Here `newDict` is

```
{'updateVirtualVolumeMetaData': [['0-250ms', 96], ['250-500ms', 0], ['500-750ms', 2], ['750-1000ms', 0], ['1000-1250ms', 0], ['1250-1500ms', 0], ['1500-1750ms', 0], ['1750-2000ms', 0], ['2000-2250ms', 0]], 'updateStorageProfileForVirtualVolume': [['0-250ms', 1], ['250-500ms', 0], ['500-750ms', 0], ['750-1000ms', 0], ['1000-1250ms', 0], ['1250-1500ms', 0], ['1500-1750ms', 0], ['1750-2000ms', 0], ['2000-2250ms', 0]], 'unsharedChunksVirtualVolume': [['0-250ms', 21], ['250-500ms', 0], ['500-750ms', 0], ['750-1000ms', 0], ['1000-1250ms', 0], ['1250-1500ms', 0], ['1500-1750ms', 0], ['1750-2000ms', 0], ['2000-2250ms', 0]], 'unbindVirtualVolume': [['0-250ms', 60], ['250-500ms', 2], ['500-750ms', 3], ['750-1000ms', 0], ['1000-1250ms', 0], ['1250-1500ms', 0], ['1500-1750ms', 0], ['1750-2000ms', 0], ['2000-2250ms', 0]], 'unbindAllVirtualVolumesFromHost': [['0-250ms', 1], ['250-500ms', 0], ['500-750ms', 0], ['750-1000ms', 0], ['1000-1250ms', 0], ['1250-1500ms', 0], ['1500-1750ms', 0], ['1750-2000ms', 0], ['2000-2250ms', 0]], 'spaceStatsForVirtualVolume': [['0-250ms', 101], ['250-500ms', 1], ['500-750ms', 0], ['750-1000ms', 0], ['1000-1250ms', 0], ['1250-1500ms', 0], ['1500-1750ms', 0], ['1750-2000ms', 0], ['2000-2250ms', 0]], 'setStorageContainerContext': [['0-250ms', 2], ['250-500ms', 0], ['500-750ms', 0], ['750-1000ms', 0], ['1000-1250ms', 0], ['1250-1500ms', 0], ['1500-1750ms', 0], ['1750-2000ms', 0], ['2000-2250ms', 0]], 'setContext': [['0-250ms', 0], ['250-500ms', 0], ['500-750ms', 2], ['750-1000ms', 0], ['1000-1250ms', 0], ['1250-1500ms', 0], ['1500-1750ms', 0], ['1750-2000ms', 0], ['2000-2250ms', 0]], 'queryVirtualVolume': [['0-250ms', 200], ['250-500ms', 0], ['500-750ms', 5], ['750-1000ms', 0], ['1000-1250ms', 0], ['1250-1500ms', 0], ['1500-1750ms', 0], ['1750-2000ms', 0], ['2000-2250ms', 0]], 'queryArrays': [['0-250ms', 4], ['250-500ms', 0], ['500-750ms', 0], ['750-1000ms', 0], ['1000-1250ms', 0], ['1250-1500ms', 0], ['1500-1750ms', 0], ['1750-2000ms', 0], ['2000-2250ms', 0]]}
```

It is showing values in list `[]` and not as dictionary `{}`.
I'd like the inner key and values as dict not as list.

Comment: What have you tried, why did it fail?

Comment: op = dict(list(dictLatency.items())[i:i+10])
      print(op)
      inner_keys = ['0-250ms', '250-500ms', '500-750ms', '750-1000ms', '1000-1250ms',
                    '1250-1500ms', '1500-1750ms', '1750-2000ms', '2000-2250ms']
      newDict = a:[{i, b.get(i, 0)} for i in inner_keys] for a, b in op.items()
      print(newDict)

      labels = op.keys()

Comment: I don't understand your added information. I thought plotting the given nested dictionary as a grouped bar graph was the task but your code transforms the dictionary into another dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the outer dictionary, and then through the inner one to draw a stacked bar graph:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np

dictLatency = {'uvvm': {'0-250ms': 96, '500-750ms': 2}, 'usvv': {'0-250ms': 1},
               'unsharedChunksVirtualVolume': {'0-250ms': 21}, 'ubvv': {'0-250ms': 60, '250-500ms': 2, '500-750ms': 3},
               'unbvvh': {'0-250ms': 1}, 'ssvv': {'0-250ms': 101, '250-500ms': 1},
               'sscc': {'0-250ms': 2}, 'sc': {'500-750ms': 2},
               'qvv': {'0-250ms': 200, '500-750ms': 5}, 'qas': {'0-250ms': 4}}
inner_keys = ['0-250ms', '250-500ms', '500-750ms', '750-1000ms', '1000-1250ms',
              '1250-1500ms', '1500-1750ms', '1750-2000ms', '2000-2250ms']
# colors = plt.cm.Set3.colors
colors = plt.cm.hsv(np.linspace(0, 0.8, len(inner_keys)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 4))
for outerkey, innerdict in dictLatency.items():
    bottom = 0
    if outerkey == 'unsharedChunksVirtualVolume':
        outerkey = 'unshared\nChunks\nVirtual\nVolume'
    for innerkey, value in innerdict.items():
        ax.bar([outerkey], [value], bottom=bottom, color=colors[inner_keys.index(innerkey)])
        bottom += value
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
legend_handles = [Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, color=color, label=label) for color, label in zip(colors, inner_keys)]
ax.legend(handles=legend_handles)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: For horizontal bars you could change the call to `ax.bar` to:

```py
ax.barh(y=outerkey, width=value, left=bottom, color=colors[inner_keys.index(innerkey)])
```

Comment: Can this be done without matplotlib? Is it possible to plot graphs in python using some default packages that come along with python installation. We have a requirement that we should not install additional packages using pip or anyother.

Comment: You really need a package at least capable of drawing on the screen. Matplotlib is the most widely used.  You added a matplotlib tag to your question, which even runs on Raspberry Pis. You should at least have indicated one package you can use. One could draw some simplistic bar chart with only ascii characters, but that would be an entirely different question. And not really suitable for your data.

Comment: Thanks for the code above. It works great. But I have a issue. I have 10 elements in inner_key

Comment: `Set2` only has 8 colors, but `Set3` has 12.  See https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html for more choices.

Comment: Thank a lot. This works wonders.One more thing. plt.show() is showing a much better graph with nice resolution but plt.savefig(pathToGraph + '/Latency.jpg', dpi=100, bbox_inches = 'tight', orientation='landscape') is saving a graph which is not looking as good as plt.show(). What parameters should I use to get the resultant saved image as good as image from plt.show()?

Comment: A higher dpi will give better quality, but will also be larger.